# How to use index files inside vendor assets folders?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, asset-pipeline

I am using Rails 3.1.12 and having trouble properly organizing vendor assets in the application.

What I want to do is use an index per each library to automatically load all its assets with one statement, just like it's specified in [the guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#using-index-files). The folder structure is like this:

```
/vendor
--/assets
----/libraries/
------/jquery.ui/
--------/index.js
--------/javascripts ...
--------/stylesheets ...
--------/images ...
```

I know that Rails automatically adds all folders inside `/vendor/assets/` to the asset search path, I can even see this path in the list when I print the `Rails.application.config.assets.paths` array in the console.

But for some reason the following require statement does not work inside neither my JS files, nor SASS files:

```
//= require jquery.ui
```

Using that statement gives the following error:

```
error = #<Sprockets::FileNotFound: couldn't find file 'jquery.ui'>
```

This works, though

```
//= require jquery.ui/index
```

How do I make the first one work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out that the problem was in the library name. When I moved the library from

```
vendor/assets/libraries/jquery.ui
```

to

```
vendor/assets/libraries/jquery-ui
```

and replaced

```
//= require jquery.ui
```

with

```
//= require jquery-ui
```

everything started working properly, the `index.js` and `index.sass` files that are located inside the `jquery-ui` folder are now being loaded properly!

Comment: isn't your index.js and index.css files asupposed to be directlly under libraries?

`vendor/assets/libraries/index.js`?

Answer (score 0):

Sprockets directives require that you specify a file to require. The directive `//= require jquery.ui` less Sprockets to load a file like "jquery.ui.js" or "jquery.ui.js.coffee". If you're looking to require "jquery.ui/index.js" you'll need to specify it exactly, file extension optional. Note this behavior is nearly identical to Ruby's require.

> The `require` directive functions similar to Ruby's own `require`.
>   It provides a way to declare a dependency on a file in your path
>   and ensures its only loaded once before the source file.
>
> `require` works with files in the environment path:
>
> ```
> //= require "foo.js"
> ```
>
> Extensions are optional. If your source file is ".js", it
>   assumes you are requiring another ".js".
>
> ```
> //= require "foo"
> ```
>
> Relative paths work too. Use a leading `./` to denote a relative
>   path:
>
> ```
> //= require "./bar"
> ```

You could opt to use a different directive such as `require_tree`, which will require all files in the specified directory: `require_tree ./jquery.ui`. Note, however, that you'll need to use a n explicit relative path (e.g. `require_tree ./jquery.ui` vs `require_tree jquery.ui`.) Also, it's important to note that the files will be required alphabetically, so make sure your code is order agnostic before using `require_tree`.

Comment: OK, I think I can live with that, but what about this? http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#using-index-files Why do index files work inside `app/assets`?

Comment: What do you have in your index file?

Comment: Only comments and other require statements like `//= require jquery.ui.effects`. Those files are required from a gem.

Comment: And what do you mean by "doesn't worK"? Do you get a `FileNotFound` error?